# sideways threeparttable: the quest for using equations as items to shorten mammoth-sized equations

Tags: equations, itemize, threeparttable

> **EDIT: The MWE as been redesigned as requested.**

I'm trying to use `threeparttable` together with `sidewaystable` to produce a table with some mammoth-type equations. In order to improve readability (see definition below), I've condensed some lenghty terms by use of a parameter - C{0}, C{1}, C{2}, C{0} - which are described in the `tablenotes` section of the table.

> ***readability***: *the art of fitting all equations in one page in order no to have to skip between two pages to understand the meaning of it
>   all, and making people wonder how you pulled that miracle out*

It compiled with some errors, giving rise to the following dog's dinner:

[image]

Itemization has, of course, changed the style of it. The size inconsistencies in the equation size are somewhat unavoidable due to the options used (as described in the MWE), but it would great to have the size 'standardized'.

In essence, how can I use threeparttable to produce a neatly formatted table where the items are just equations describing variables?

Any help would be most welcome!

**The *updated* MWE**

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

%** Preamble **
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%** End of Preamble **

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable*}[p]
 \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{Matrix elements of the electric dipole operator $\hat{p}_{0}^{1}$}
   \label{C1-tb8} % should go after \caption
    \sisetup{table-align-text-post=false}
     \setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}
      \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l l}
        \toprule
        {$J', K'$} & {$\langle JKIF \vert \hat{H}_{Q} \vert J'K'IF\rangle$} \\
        \midrule
        $J, K$          & $C_{1}[3K^{2}-J(J+1)]\chi_{0}$\\
        $J, K+1$        & $C_{1}(2K+1)[\frac{3}{2}(2K+1)(J-K)]^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\chi_{-1}$\\
        $J, K+2$        & $C_{1}[\frac{3}{2}(J+K+1)(J+K+2)(J-K)(J-K-1)]^{\tfrac{1}{2}} \chi_{-2}$\\
        $J+1, K$        & $-3C_{2}K[(J+1)^{2}-K^{2}]^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\chi_{0}$\\
        $J+1, K\pm 1$   & $-C_{2}[(J \mp K)(J\pm K+2)(J\pm K+1)]^{\tfrac{1}{2}} \chi_{\mp 1}$\\
        $J+1, K\pm 2$   & $\pm C_{2}[\frac{3}{2}(J \mp K)(J \pm K +1)(J \pm K +2)(J \pm K + 3)]^{\tfrac{1}{2}} \chi_{ \mp 1}$\\
        $J+2, K$        & $3C_{3}[((J+1)^{2}-k^{2})((J+2)^{2})-K^{2}]^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\chi_{0}$\\
        $J+2, K\pm 1$   & $\mp 2C_{3}[\frac{3}{2}(J-K+1)(J+K+1+)(J\pm K +2)(J\pm K +3)]^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\chi_{ \mp 1}$\\
        $J+2, K\pm 1$   & $C_{3}[\frac{3}{2}(J \pm K +1)(J \pm K +2)(J \pm K +3)(J \pm K +4)^{\tfrac{1}{2}}]\chi_{ \mp 2}$\\
      \end{tabular*}
     \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize\smallskip\raggedright          
    \item[$C_{0}$]$=F(F+1)-I(I+1)-J(J+1)$
    \item[$C_{1}$]$=\tfrac{3C_{0}(C_{0}+1)}{[2I(2I-1)(J+1)(2J-1)(2J+3)][4-I(I+1)J(J+1)]}$
    \item[$C_{2}$]$=\tfrac{F(F+1)-I(I+1)-J(J+2)}{8I(2I-1)J(J+1)(J+2)}[\tfrac{(F+I+J+2)(J+I-F+1)(F+J-I+1)(F+I-J)}{(2J+1)(2J+3)}]^{\tfrac{1}{2}}$
    \item[$C_{3}$]$=\tfrac{1}{16I(2I-1)J(J+1)(J+2)(2J+3)}[\tfrac{(F+I-J)(F+I+J+2)(F+I+J+3)}{(2J+1)(2J+5)}] \times [(I-F+J+1)(I-F+J+2)(F-I+J+1)(F-I+J+2)(F+I-J-1)]^{\tfrac{1}2}$
     \end{tablenotes}
 \end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable*}
```

Comment: Please compose from your codes fragments one small, but complete document, which we can test. In preamble let it has only packages necessary to compose your table and define page layout (without header, footer). Help us to help you! BTW, long equation you can break into multiline equations using math environments from `asmath` or `mathtools`.

Comment: @Zarko, I use IEEEtrantools.

Comment: This information doesn't help much. We still need to compose MWE (this time I wrote it exceptional, however, it may not reproduce all your problems). In future, please always provide MWE and don't require that people, who willing to help you repeat a work which you already done at writing your document.

Answer (score 1):

From your code fragments I try to compose MWE (Minimal working example), a small but complete document which which is supposed to reproduce your problem.

I would not use `threeparttable`. Instead `tablenotes` I suggest to use simple text and `aligned` math environment for equations:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable*}[p]
  \caption{Matrix elements of the electric dipole operator $\hat{p}_{0}^{1}$}
   \label{C1-tb8} % should go after \caption
      \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{*{2}{>{$}l<{$}}}
        \toprule
J', K'          & \langle JKIF \vert \hat{H}_{Q} \vert J'K'IF\rangle    \\
\midrule
J, K          & C_{1}\bigl[3K^{2}-J(J+1)\bigr]\chi_{0}\\
J, K+1        & C_{1}(2K+1)\bigl[\frac{3}{2}(2K+1)(J-K)\bigr]^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\chi_{-1}\\
J, K+2        & C_{1}\bigl[\frac{3}{2}(J+K+1)(J+K+2)(J-K)(J-K-1)\bigr]^{\tfrac{1}{2}} \chi_{-2}\\
J+1, K        & -3C_{2}K\bigl[(J+1)^{2}-K^{2}\bigr]^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\chi_{0}\\
J+1, K\pm 1   & -C_{2}\bigl[(J \mp K)(J\pm K+2)(J\pm K+1)\bigr]^{\tfrac{1}{2}} \chi_{\mp 1}\\
J+1, K\pm 2   & \pm C_{2}\bigl[\frac{3}{2}(J \mp K)(J \pm K +1)(J \pm K +2)
                                          (J \pm K + 3)\bigr]^{\tfrac{1}{2}} \chi_{ \mp 1}\\
J+2, K        & 3C_{3}\bigl[((J+1)^{2}-k^{2})((J+2)^{2})-K^{2}\bigr]^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\chi_{0}\\
J+2, K\pm 1   & \mp 2C_{3}\bigl[\frac{3}{2}(J-K+1)(J+K+1+)(J\pm K +2)
                                           (J\pm K +3)\bigr]^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\chi_{ \mp 1}\\
J+2, K\pm 1   & C_{3}\bigl[\frac{3}{2}(J \pm K +1)(J \pm K +2)(J \pm K +3)
                                      (J \pm K +4)^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\bigr]\chi_{\mp 2}\\
      \midrule
      \end{tabular*}

Where are:\\[1ex]  
\small  
$\begin{aligned}
    C_{0} & = F(F+1)-I(I+1)-J(J+1)                                  \\
    C_{1} & = \frac{3C_{0}(C_{0}+1)}
                   {[2I(2I-1)(J+1)(2J-1)(2J+3)][4-I(I+1)J(J+1)]}    \\[1ex]
    C_{2} & = \dfrac{F(F+1)-I(I+1)-J(J+2)}{8I(2I-1)J(J+1)(J+2)}
                \biggl[\dfrac{(F+I+J+2)(J+I-F+1)(F+J-I+1)(F+I-J)}
                            {(2J+1)(2J+3)}\biggr]^{\frac{1}{2}}     \\[1ex]
    C_{3} & = \dfrac{1}{16I(2I-1)J(J+1)(J+2)(2J+3)}
                \biggl[\dfrac{(F+I-J)(F+I+J+2)(F+I+J+3)}{(2J+1)(2J+5)}\biggr]\times%
                \biggl[(I-F+J+1)(I-F+J+2)(F-I+J+1)(F-I+J+2)(F+I-J-1)\biggr]^{\tfrac{1}2}
\end{aligned}$
    \end{sidewaystable*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's an interesting solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Strelok, only interesting :-( ?

Comment: *feeding ego* - an interesting solution for me is quite a compliment! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you load `geometry`, (this supposes you don't use marginal notes), your table can fit text width, and anyway, you don't need `threeparttable`: just add another row and a `\multicolumn`, and use the `medsize` environment from `nccmath` and `multlined` from `mathtools`. I also took the opportunity to improve the placement of the  indices of the letter `χ`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{book}
%% Avoiding extra whitespaces between paragraphs
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{geometry}
% *********************************** Charset & Language *********************************
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{epigraph}

% *********************************** Chemistry *********************************
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} % are they incompatible?

% *********************************** SI Units *********************************
\usepackage{siunitx} % use this package module for SI units

% *********************************** Graphics *********************************
%\usepackage{awesomebox} % this package is awesome (lol) but I need to explore it more
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
%\usepackage{subfigure}

% *********************************** Equations *********************************
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools} % This specifies the IEEEtrantools package for beautiful equations in LaTeX
% \usepackage{l3packages} % for tidy fractions
%\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

% ********************************** Tables ************************************
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % for vertical align of image
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}

% *****************************************************************************
% *************************** Bibliography and References ********************
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes,xpatch}
\usepackage{linegoal}
% ******************************************************************************
% ************************* User Defined Commands ******************************
% ******************************************************************************
\newcommand{\tn}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\TN}[1]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\tn{#1}}}

% To set the University Crest at the center of the page
\newcommand\AlCentroPagina[1]{%
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\AtPageCenter{%
\makebox(0,0){\includegraphics%
[width=0.9\paperwidth]{#1}}}}}

% *********** To change the name of Table of Contents / LOF and LOT ************

%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{My Table of Contents}
%\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{My List of Figures}
%\renewcommand{\listtablename}{My List of Tables}

% ********************** TOC depth and numbering depth *************************
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

% ******************************** New Macros **********************************
\newcommand{\dvt}{\dv{}{t}}
\newcommand{\bracket}[3]{\(\langle #1 \lvert #2 \rvert #3 \rangle\)}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\newcommand{\attrib}[1]{%
    \nopagebreak{\raggedleft\footnotesize #1\par}}
\renewcommand{\poemtitlefont}{\normalfont\large\itshape\centering}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!htp]
  \caption{Matrix elements of the electric dipole operator $\hat{p}_{0}^{1}$}
   \label{C1-tb8} % should go after \caption
    \sisetup{table-align-text-post=false}
     \setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}
      \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{*{2}l}
        \toprule
        {$J', K'$} & {$\langle JKIF \vert \hat{H}_{Q} \vert J'K'IF\rangle$} \\
        \midrule
        $J, K$ & $C_{1}[3K^{2}-J(J+1)]\chi_{0}$\\
        $J, K+1$ & $C_{1}(2K+1)[\frac{3}{2}(2K+1)(J-K)]^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\chi_{_{\scriptstyle -1}}$\\
        $J, K+2$ & $C_{1}[\frac{3}{2}(J+K+1)(J+K+2)(J-K)(J-K-1)]^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\chi_{_{\scriptstyle -2}}$\\
        $J+1, K$ & $-3C_{2}K[(J+1)^{2}-K^{2}]^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\chi_{_{\scriptstyle 0}}$\\
        $J+1, K±1$ & $-C_{2}[(J ∓ K)(J± K+2)(J± K+1)]^{\tfrac{1}{2} \chi_{_{\scriptstyle ∓ 1}}}$\\
        $J+1, K±2$ & $± C_{2}[\frac{3}{2}(J ∓ K)(J ± K +1)(J ± K +2)(J ± K + 3)]^{\tfrac{1}{2}} \chi_{_{\scriptstyle ∓ 1}}$\\
        $J+2, K$ & $3C_{3}[((J+1)^{2}-k^{2})((J+2)^{2})-K^{2}]^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\chi_{_{\scriptstyle 0}}$\\
        $J+2, K±1$ & $∓ 2C_{3}[\frac{3}{2}(J-K+1)(J+K+1+)(J± K +2)(J± K +3)]^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\chi_{_{\scriptstyle ∓ 1}}$\\
        $J+2, K±1$ & $C_{3}[\frac{3}{2}(J ± K +1)(J ± K +2)(J ± K +3)(J ± K +4)^{\tfrac{1}{2}}]\chi_{_{\scriptstyle ∓ 2}}$ \\[2ex]
 \multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth}}{
{where:}\enspace \smash{\rule[-28.3ex]{0.4pt}{30ex}}\enspace $\begin{medsize}
\begin{aligned}[t]
\text C_{0} & =F(F+1)-I(I+1)-J(J+1)\\[0.5ex]
  C_{1} & =\frac{3C_{0}(C_{0}+1)}{\bigl[2I(2I-1)(J+1)(2J-1)(2J+3)\bigr]\bigl[4-I(I+1)J(J+1)\bigr]} \\[1ex]
  C_{2} &=\begin{multlined}[t] \frac{F(F+1)-I(I+1)-J(J+2)}{8I(2I-1)J(J+1)(J+2)}\times{}\\[-1ex] \biggl[ \frac{(F+I+J+2)(J+I-F+1)(F+J-I+1)(F+I-J)}{(2J+1)(2J+3)}\biggr]^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\end{multlined}\\[1ex]
  C_{3} & =\begin{multlined}[t]\frac{1}{16I(2I-1)J(J+1)(J+2)} \biggl[\frac{(F+I-J)(F+I+J+2)(F+I+J+3)}{(2J+1)(2J+3)(2J+5)}\biggr] ×{}\\[-1ex] \bigl[(I-F+J+1)(I-F+J+2)(F-I+J+1)(F-I+J+2)(F+I-J-1)\bigr]^{\tfrac{1}2}\end{multlined}
\end{aligned}
\end{medsize}$
}
      \end{tabular*}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]